# Is there any example in Couchbase PhoneGap with REST API

Tags: couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

There are some examples that were developed with Couchbase Lite PhoneGap plugin but there is no example with REST API and PhoneGap plugin.

Can we use REST APIs with PhoneGap plugin in Couchbase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curious what is your use case in using REST APIs with the PhoneGap plugin for Couchbase Mobile?
What are you trying to do and best to post your questions on the [Couchbase Mobile Forum](http://forums.couchbase.com/c/mobile/couchbase-lite)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I could not find anything so I wrote a TypeScript API for the REST API. Keep reading for a JS version. You can take a look here [cordova-plugin-couchbase-lite](https://github.com/happieio/cordova-plugin-couchbase-lite) or on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-couchbase-lite)

There is an example project embedded in the test folder to see how it integrates.

Both are written in Typescript, so the source would need to be compiled to use in a JS project. The test app is configured to generate the JS for you if need be.